# MongoDB + PHP: Delete a value of a sub array

Tags: php, mongodb, pull

I have a document in the following form:

```
[uuid] => d030b8d1
[commentstrings] => Array (
    [0] => 1366220389#mac@test.org#test 1
    [1] => 1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2
    [2] => 1366220458#mac@test.org#test 3
)
```

I have a full string of one of the commentstrings and want to delete that value.

If I try this on CLI, it works:

```
 db.messages.update(
     {'uuid':'d030b8d1'}, 
     { $pull : {
         'commentstrings': '1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2'
     }} 
 )
```

But if I try the same in PHP nothing happens:

```
$response = $stdb->messages->update(
    array('uuid'=>'d030b8d1'),
    array('$pull' => array('commentstrings' => '1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2'))
);
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not get this behaviour:

```
$mongodb->ghghghg->insert(array('uuid' => 'd030b8d1',
        'commentstrings' => Array (
            '1366220389#mac@test.org#test 1',
            '1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2',
            '1366220458#mac@test.org#test 3'
)));

var_dump($mongodb->ghghghg->findOne());

$response = $mongodb->ghghghg->update(
        array('uuid'=>'d030b8d1'),
        array('$pull' => array('commentstrings' => '1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2'))
);

var_dump($mongodb->ghghghg->findOne());
```

Prints:

```
array
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[19]
      public '$id' => string '516ffff96803fa2261000000' (length=24)
  'uuid' => string 'd030b8d1' (length=8)
  'commentstrings' => 
    array
      0 => string '1366220389#mac@test.org#test 1' (length=30)
      1 => string '1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2' (length=30)
      2 => string '1366220458#mac@test.org#test 3' (length=30)

array
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[18]
      public '$id' => string '516ffff96803fa2261000000' (length=24)
  'commentstrings' => 
    array
      0 => string '1366220389#mac@test.org#test 1' (length=30)
      1 => string '1366220458#mac@test.org#test 3' (length=30)
  'uuid' => string 'd030b8d1' (length=8)
```

What version of the driver are you on and also your PHP version?

Also are you sure that `commentstrings` IS an array? Look in the MongoDB console, not through PHP and see what it print it out like.

Comment: Thanks for your testcase - it is working here too.

I found the problem - it was a typo an a variable! :-/

Thanks for helping!

Comment: @blitzkid heh we all do it :) glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$response = $stdb->messages->update(array('uuid'=>'d030b8d1'),array('$pull' => array('commentstrings' => '1366220422\#mac\@test.org\#test 2')));
```

Comment: I can't use the mongo id. I already found the item over it's own uuid. Problem is to delete one of the commentstrings.

Comment: maybe problem is on `1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2` put `1366220422\#mac\@test.org\#test 2` instead and try again

Comment: or maybe problem is on mongodb. reset mongodb and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$data = array('$pull' => array('commentstrings' => '1366220422#mac@test.org#test 2'));
$response = $stdb->messages->update(array('uuid'=>'d030b8d1'), $data);
var_dump($response);
```

What returns ?

Comment: `[updatedExisting] => 
    [n] => 0
    [connectionId] => 2314
    [err] => 
    [ok] => 1'


Seems ok, but does not delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my code was correct. It was a typo in a variable.